# Referencing value and values after it

Tags: python, list, reference, concatenation

Let's say I have a list:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

I want a loop that will, for every value, check if a concatenated version of it and any other beyond it are the same as an existing value in another list. Make sense? No? Here's what I want to come out.

**The lists**

```
list1 = ['3','ex','fish nets','orange','banana','exampl','apple']
list2 = ['e','x','blah','exam','p','l','blahblah']
```

Finally, we take these lists and let's say I want every time a value and any adjacent number of values after it are equivalent to a value in `list1` for them to concatenate. (i.e. values *e* and *x* concatenate to be *ex* which exists in `list1`.) So, it modifies `list2` to be:

```
list2 = ['ex','blah','exam','p','l','blahblah']
```

The same would be for three or four or however many values are in the list. The loop would reexamine the rest of possible combinations (only left -> right) and do the same. *exam*, *p*, and *l* concatenate to the value in `list1` *exampl*. `list2` then becomes:

```
list2 = ['ex','blah','exampl','blahblah']
```

The wording on this is pretty poor but I hope the examples were in-depth enough to give a representation of what I need.

Comment: What have you done until now? This is not a free-code network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list1 = ['3','ex','fish nets','orange','banana','exampl','apple']
list2 = ['e','x','blah','exam','p','l','blahblah']
a=list2
j=['e','x','blah','exam','p','l','blahblah']
t=[]
for y in range(0, len(j)):
            for i in range(1,len(j)-y):
                    r=''    
                    t=j[y:y+i+1]    #Create a list of adjacent elements.
                    for x in t:
                        r+=str(x)    #make it string and check if it fits.
                    if r in list1:
                        list2[y]=r
                        for e in range(y+1,y+i+1):
                            list2[e]=0    # to avoid a mess with indexes.
while 0 in list2:
    list2.remove(0) 
print list2
```

I know it's very clumpsy, but it seems to work.